# напиши код на питоне, который будет выдавать 15 чисел в строку

Tags: python

```
import random as rn

print(rn.randint(1, 100))
```

Comment: Формулировочка страдает.. Неясно, каких чисел

Comment: судя по тому, что человек импортирует библиотеку random, то предполагаю, что случайных.

Answer (score 1):

15 случайных чисел в строку:

```
import random

line=''
for i in range (15):
    line+=str(random.randint(1,100))+' '
print (line[0:len(line)-1])
```

Comment: вместо `line[0:len(line)-1]` лучше писать просто `line[:-1]`